# ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages. am using iText

Tags: java, itext

when i execute the below code

```
File f = new File("c:/sample.pdf");
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(f));
document.open();
System.out.println("opening the document..");
PdfPTable headerTable=new PdfPTable(9);
PdfPCell cellValue = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Header 1"));
cellValue.setColspan(1);
headerTable.addCell(cellValue);
cellValue = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Header 2"));
headerTable.addCell(cellValue);
cellValue = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Header 3"));
headerTable.addCell(cellValue);
cellValue = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Header 4"));
headerTable.addCell(cellValue);

PdfPTable subHeaderTable = new PdfPTable(3);
PdfPCell subHeadingCell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Header 5"));
subHeadingCell.setColspan(3);
subHeaderTable.addCell(subHeadingCell);
subHeaderTable.addCell("Sub heading 1");
subHeaderTable.addCell("Sub heading 2"); 
subHeaderTable.addCell("Sub heading 3");

headerTable.addCell(subHeaderTable);

document.add(headerTable);
document.close();
```

I get below exception. please help

```
ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPages.writePageTree(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.Document.close(Unknown Source)
```

PLEASE HELP FRIENDS. THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: You should compile your code with the debug flag set. That will make it easier to find problems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay so I tried it out for you. My previous answer was incorrect, declaring the file first works as well. I think that your table declaration is wrong. You set it to 9 columns, but you only fill 5 of them. If you would change your columnssize of the headerTable to 5 that should fix it.

Answer (score 4):

You get this error when the compiler does not get any meaningful information to write to your file. I suggest trying to add this line after `open()`

```
document.add(new Chunk(""));
```

It should work

Comment: please improve your code formatting so it becomes easier to read.

Comment: *"the compiler"* - you surely mean the *document*, not the *compiler*...

Answer (score 2):

I guess Aries51's solution worked for you. One additional note: you dont seem to catch your exceptions at all. A big try-catch around everything in your main-method (or a throwing main-method) is not the way to use exceptions. For example you should wrap a try-catch around Aries51's suggestion of `PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("c:/sample.pdf"));` because at some point you will replace the static `c:/...` sample string with a string the user enters at runtime. An exception should tell you if that file is writable or if it exists at all (user can enter bogus).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used Aries solution, still its not working. What I guess is, since i have given                  PdfPTable headerTable=new PdfPTable(9);                        
It doesnt have page-space to print rest of the heading.. same works if i change the value from 9 to 2.. so pls tell me how to reduce the size of the cell (if my guess is right)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
File f = new File("c:/sample.pdf");
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(f));
```

by

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("c:/sample.pdf"));
```

I don't see anything wrong besides that...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem .
My pdf was created fine in netbeans but the executable jar was not doing so.

Finally debugging my codes **I found that the file "watermark.png" which i was using to add in my pdf was not put together the "distbuild.jar" .**

I put the file "watermark.png" with that executable jar file and now the error is resolved.

Check if you are also having all your files with the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when accidentally trying to close the PDF twice. Simple solution to eliminate one of the calls.

Answer (score 0):

table declaration wrong.

PdfPTable patTable = AgsiPdfPUtil.getTable(10);//declared table

you declared 10 columns so you should use 10 columns

Comment: Hi - thanks for trying to help. But this is the same point as the already accepted answer?