# document has no pages with itext

Tags: java, itext

```
<%
OutputStream output=response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=details.pdf");
try{
    Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);
document.open();
XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/a", "root", "root");
Statement st=con.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
List arrlist = new ArrayList();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from user_start1");
 while(rs.next()){
 arrlist.add(rs.getString("data"));
 }  
for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
  String str =(String) arrlist.get(i);
  System.out.println(str); 
  worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, new StringReader("helloworld"));
}
document.close();
writer.flush();
writer.close();
output.close();
}catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();} 
%>
```

throws an error

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/chieflegis] threw exception [ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.] with root cause
java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPages.writePageTree(PdfPages.java:113)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(PdfWriter.java:1217)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:807)
    at com.itextpdf.text.Document.close(Document.java:416)
    at org.apache.jsp.print_jsp._jspService(print_jsp.java:112)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I have used the same xmlworker previously but never had any errors.even hellowworld isnt displayed.please help

Comment: check if this is useful http://stackoverflow.com/q/6816195/2006839

Comment: didnt work.no idea why hello world also doesnt display

Comment: Would it work if you pull the worker.parseXhtml line outside the loop? Maybe works once, but fails on the repeat?

Comment: doesnt work outside the for loop also....same doc has no pages error

Comment: The XHTML that you are asking it to parse "helloworld" is not a true XHTML text. Try wrapping it in XHTML tags. It is the close that is failing.

Comment: I didnt get you?could you give me a line?

Comment: you were right.@Krazick...thanks for the help

Comment: Actually with further thought the stack trace is when it tries to close the PDFWriter. At that point you have already closed the document, so it would have no pages. Move the document close after the PDFWrite close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml()` expects (X)HTML or (X)HTML snippets.  Try this:

```
worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, new StringReader("<p>helloworld</p>"));
```

Answer (score 35):

Other answers are good. This is an alternative.

In general, to prevent this error which often occurs when the document contains no meaningful data for content, even despite `document.open()` and `document.newPage()` having been called, and even after stamping other pages into that document, you can add an empty chunk when the document is opened to ensure the library never considers it empty. e.g.

```
document.open(); 
document.add(new Chunk("")); // << this will do the trick.
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to new a page just like `document.newPage()` before you write something to document, hope that helps.

Comment: surprising thing is hello world also doesnt display

Comment: Try to call writer.setPageEmpty(true) right after document.open(), and what happens?

Comment: nothing happened ,it gave the same error.document has no pages.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's a bit late to this answer, but in my case just upgraded iTextSharp to v. 5.5 from 5.0 and started to work correctly.

Answer (score -1):

`document.add(new Chunk(""));` worked for me after `document.open();` when the data is not there in the report text.