# How convert template HTML with images to PDF in ServiceNow?

Tags: javascript, pdf, servicenow

I need to create dynamic pdf with html templates in servicenow, but my problem is that these pdf must contain images and styles, and I have not been able to solve it.

try using the api of GeneralPDF of servicenow and get the template converted to pdf but only when it contains text. when I put images I get the following error:

This error appears to me when executing my code:

> ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.:
>   org.mozilla.javascript.JavaScriptException: ExceptionConverter:
>   java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.:

this is in a script include and is called from UI Action
my code to convert the html to pdf is the following:

```
create : function (sys_id){ 

   var carta = new GlideRecord('x_solsa_casos_plant_doc');
    carta.addQuery('sys_id','6f1e4ac8db29f300ab7c0f95ca96197a');
    carta.query();
    if(carta.next()){
        var parsedBody = carta.body;
        var gr = new GlideRecord('x_solsa_casos_x_solsa_casos');
        gr.get('sys_id',sys_id);
        var sampleString=parsedBody.toString();
        var reg = new SNC.Regex('/\\$\\{(.*?)\\}/i');
        var match = reg.match(sampleString);
        var count =0;
        var variables = [];
        var values = [];
        var tmpValue;
        while (match != null) 
        {
            variables.push(match.toString().substring(match.toString().indexOf(',')+1));
            match = reg.match();
            values.push(variables[count]);
            gs.log("array values : " + values);
            if(gr.getDisplayValue(values[count])==null || JSUtil.nil(gr.getDisplayValue(values[count])))
            {
                tmpValue='';
            }else{
                tmpValue=gr.getDisplayValue(values[count]);
                gs.log("tmpValue :" +tmpValue);
            }
            parsedBody = parsedBody.replace('${'+variables[count]+'}', tmpValue);
                count++;
                gs.log("parsedBody : " + parsedBody);
        }
        this.createPDF(parsedBody,'x_solsa_casos_x_solsa_casos',sys_id,'carta.pdf');  
    }
```

},

```
createPDF : function(html, table, sys_id, filename) {
  var pdfDoc = new GeneralPDF.Document(null, null, null, null, null, null);
  this._document = new GeneralPDF(pdfDoc);
  this._document.startHTMLParser();
  this._document.addHTML(html);
  this._document.stopHTMLParser();
  this.saveAs(table, sys_id, filename);
```

},

```
saveAs : function (table, sys_id, filename){
  var att = new GeneralPDF.Attachment();
  att.setTableName(table);
  att.setTableId(sys_id);
  att.setName(filename);
  att.setType('application/pdf');
  att.setBody(this._document.get());
  GeneralPDF.attach(att);
```

},

Comment: have you ever heard of itextpdf? it's a really easy way to convert html templates to pdf, if you are interested, you should check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `parsedBody` is empty or doesn't always contain HTML. According to this answer, paseXHtml (which ServiceNow probably uses and should be in the complete stack trace) expects HTML tags, not just text:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20902124/2157581